# VIM Doxygen support - auto asterisk (*) insertion on newline

Tags: c++, c, vim, doxygen

When I write Doxygen comments (in C file) I would like an asterisk to be automatically inserted on new line (either with the `o` command or just ↩ ).

Like this example :

```
/** 
 * My Doxygen comment being written
```

And when I hit ↩

```
/**
 * My Doxygen comment bein written
 * 
   ^
 cursor is here
```

I have DoxygenToolkit.vim and `set syntax=c.doxygen` but none does what I want.
I also found [that](http://vim.wikia.com/wiki/Continuing_doxygen_comments) but not sure what it is supposed to do, but doesn't solve my problem.
I've googled for it but did not find.

Any idea?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need this in your `~/.vimrc`:

```
filetype plugin indent on
```

I don't know about DoxygenToolkit.vim, I have never used it. The above is all it takes to enable the described behaviour in my 7.x Vims.

You can find my [commented ~/.vimrc](http://www.rootdirectory.de/wiki/.vimrc) online. Nothing too fancy in there, just what I use every day on half a dozen different Linux / AIX boxes. Perhaps there is more in there that you would like.

Comment: This does indeed work. What does this have to do with auto-adding asterisks to comments? What other effects does this have?

Comment: @sherrellbc It activates Vim's filetype-dependent auto-indentation, which includes automated "comment continuation".

Answer (score 3):

```
:setlocal formatoptions+=ro
```

does that (`:help fo-table`).

> o Automatically insert the current comment leader after hitting 'o' or
>     'O' in Normal mode.
>   r Automatically insert the current comment leader after hitting
>   <Enter> in Insert mode.

Put this into `~/.vim/after/ftplugin/c.vim`. (This requires that you have `:filetype plugin on`; use of the *after* directory allows you to override any default filetype settings done by `$VIMRUNTIME/ftplugin/c.vim`.) Alternatively, you could define an `:autocmd FileType c ...` directly in your `~/.vimrc`, but this tends to become unwieldy once you have many customizations.

Comment: Note that `c.vim` does contain this by default, you do not have to touch that! All you need is to enable it with `:filetype plugin on`